# Switching a decimal higher than 24 into [hh]:mm:ss format?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have an integer greater than 24 and I would like to switch it in date format. All I can get is a mistmatch error.

```
Dim ready_time() as Date

Dim time_calculator as Integer
```

Here I have code that will increment the time_calculator

```
ready_time(i) = Format((time_calculator / 24), "[hh]:mm:ss")
```

If time_calculator = 36, i want to have 36:00:00. This value will be used later, so it is important that I don't use the TEXT/String function.

Thank you for your help, I'm trying to solve this for 5 hours now!

Comment: Just put it in as (time_calculator / 24) then format it when pulling it out, whether by code with `Range.NumberFormat` or on the worksheet with a custom format.

Comment: Hello @ScottCraner . If I only keep the (time_calculator / 24), is it going to affect my data for my future calculation. I must multiply my data (ready_time(i)) with other integer. I think everything under 24:00:00 will be fine, but if it is something like 1900-01-01 02:00:00, I think it won't be ok.. am I right?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments:

```
Sub ttooo()

Dim t() As Double

ReDim t(1 To 2) As Double

t(1) = 36 / 24
t(2) = 23 / 24

Range("A1") = t(1)
Range("A2") = t(2)

Range("A1:A2").NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm:ss"

End Sub
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you sir for your time/answer!

Comment: @sexyuser1 I hope it helped.  It was too much for a comment.